# Non Ui/Main Thread is able to update ui android

Tags: android, multithreading

Why my app is able to access UI elements from a non UI thread? According to Android documentation, we can't access UI element in the non UI thread. The app is not crashed and the view is getting updated.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


private  val TAG = "MainActivity"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val tv = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv)

    Thread(Runnable(){
        Log.i(TAG, Thread.currentThread().name)

        tv.text = "Hi"

    }).start()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can never update the UI from any other threads except the MainThread/UiTHread. You can call a handler with looper.getMainLooper() which will create a handler in the main thread. Now you can update your UI within this.

Comment: Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {....} // This is your code
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);  This is a sample code to create a handler in the main thread, you will need to run this within your thread to update the UI

Comment: but why my code is working without any error